# how to know what are the possible output for the object recognition machine learning model (CoreML)

Tags: ios, machine-learning, object-recognition, coreml

The Machine Learning Model I download from Apple's website, can be used to recognise lots of different object through image.

I want to know, say I need to detect all different kinds of trees. Some can be recognised by the model whereas some cannot. Then how would I know how many trees are being trained in this model? in another word, How would I know all the possible tree recognition in this model? How would I find out? Can I decode the model? or parse it or something?

Comment: you can not decode the model. apple provide coremltools to create your own ML model with the framework: https://github.com/apple/coremltools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These models are trained on the ImageNet dataset. Here is a list of classes that these models can detect: https://github.com/HoldenCaulfieldRye/caffe/blob/master/data/ilsvrc12/synset_words.txt

Comment: So does it mean there's no way to find this list from the model itself, other than finding it in a separate file the author may or may not offer.

Comment: If the Core ML model is a classifier then it will contain that list of class names. But I'm not sure if / how you can obtain that list from the MLModel object.